# Applying SOLID principles

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I am trying to apply SOLID principles to my project, and am not sure how to handle the following scenario:

I have an interface:

```
IService
```

and a class that implements the interface

```
Service : IService
```

`IService` has a number of methods in it, and for my project, I now need to update the functionality of one of these methods, lets call it `method1`.

My understanding of SOLID is that I should not update `method1`, but instead make a new class that extends `Service` (`ServiceV2`) and override `method1`

My question is, should `ServiceV2` only extend `Service`, or does it need to implement the interface `IService`, and then extend `Service` and override `method1` only?

The main reason I ask is because if it implements `IService` this would affect my dependency injection (simple Injector), in the sense that I can only register one class that implements `IService`

I assume I would not be making a whole new `IServcieV2` and `ServiceV2` as this would then lose the relationship between `IService` and `IServicev2`

Also, if it only extends `Service`, am I still implementing dependency inversion, as the new class is not directly implementing an interface, but I suppose it is indirectly?

Comment: Have you thought of decorator pattern http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern?

Comment: Yes, a child class inherits the interfaces of its base class.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider can you explain more please - I am not sure what you mean

Comment: If `Service` implements `IService`, any child class `ServiceV2 : Service` will also implicitly implement `IService`. So you still have to tell your Dependency Injection Framework which concrete class it has to inject if an `IService` is requested, `Service` or `ServiceV2`.

Comment: SOLID is not about making a new class when you have to add some new functionality. It is perfectly fine to make your update in the existing class, as long as you apply the SOLID principles.

Comment: It think @Alex is referring to the Open/Close principle which advises that a class should be open to extension but closed to modification. Generally I think it depends on your situation. If the class in question is published and well-used (in a public api for instance) and making a change to it will cause widespread pain for consumers of it then perhaps you should consider extending it. If it is not widely used or making a change to it would have a negligible impact then perhaps it's fine to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Service` implements `IService` and `Service2` derives from `Service`, then `Service2` automatically implements `IService`, since `IService` only defines a **part of the signature** of a class viable **for a specific purpose**. This class, or freely signaturedefinition, is then used to create a Type which in turn defines the `object`s members.

The signature does not change through inheritance. It can only get extended. 
And this is basically the only thing you should use inheritance for:

If the visible behavior of `Service2.Method1()` is different from the visible behavior of `Service.Method1()` this means that the **visible behavior** of `Service2` is different from the **visible behavior** of `Service`. In that case, you shall not use inheritance, but a new class that implements `IService`. Because it is a **different Service** in that case.

Let me give you a concrete example, though in a different context:

A square is technically a special case of a rectangle which implies that `Square : Rectangle`. However, if the length of a square changes its width also changes. This is not the case for a rectangle. So if you'd have a `List<Rectangle>` containing regular `Rectangle` aswell as `Square` objects, which you could do since `Square` was defined as a Child of `Rectangle`, you would have **different visible behaviors**. Thus, `Square` cannot be the child of `Rectangle`, since you cannot use `Rectangle` in place of `Square`. So `Square : Rectangle` is false. You could have both implement an Interface `IGeometry` which defines `Length` and `Width` as Properties and use both `Rectangles` and `Squares` in a `List<IGeometry>`. An interface does not specify behaviour. Just the signature.

If you have an `IConfigService` you would likewise define the classes `FileConfigService` and `DatabaseConfigService` as `FileConfigService : IConfigService` and `DatabaseConfigService : IConfigService` and have your classes hold them as `IConfigService` since they do not have to be concerned about any kind of implementation details - they only need to know that a couple of Methods and Properties exist. That's also why you create an interface for every 'purpose' instead of a big one for everything. And why Interfaces only define public members.

This is essentially what most of SOLID boils down to.

If you only add functionality to your `IService` implementation, then only change this one class. There's nothing from stopping you.

It's a bit of a different story though if you had something like a webservice on which already existing and running systems depend on - in this case I would have a look into versioning.

Comment: if ServiceV2 extends Service, but overrides Method1, then how would I handle that using Dependency Injection, as I can only have 1 implementation of the interface IService. In this case I have decided the best course of action is to make a new method within the Service class because extending it and implementing the new method there would essentially be useless. Can I ask what your view is on this?

Comment: "This is essentially what most of SOLID boils down to.". Come on, there's a bit more to it than that.

Comment: @pmcilreavy True, Single Responsibility was missing, all other cases were covered.

Comment: @Alex It's hard to say without knowing what it is you want to actually achieve (concrete example). The easiest would be to define `Method1()` and `Method2()` as part of `IService` and let it only have one type of implementation if they do something similar. Or have a method that takes in a desicive parameter like a bool value. If that's not possible AND you are limited to one implementation per interface within injection you might want to check some conditions before injecting the proper implementation you need. If you need both, you might want to think about a proper IOC container or thelike.